# When was the last time that a major party in GB polled <2% in a constituency?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, history, statistics

The Labour Party [garnered just 1.6% of the vote](https://twitter.com/britainelects/status/1405690225263775748?s=21) in the Chesham and Amersham by-election.

When was the last time that a major party (Conservative or Labour) received <2% of the vote in a Great Britain<sup>1</sup> constituency during parliamentary elections or by-elections?

---

<sup>1</sup>Including constituencies in England, Scotland and Wales only; excludes constituencies in Northern Ireland

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Azor Ahai's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/65825/when-was-the-last-time-that-a-major-party-in-gb-polled-2-in-a-constituency/65826#65826) covers the situation with regard to general elections, but there are also a few notable by-election results for Labour - in 1997 and 1993. Technically the 1993 result is a few votes over 2%, but it's close enough! Interestingly, both by-elections were won by the Liberal Democrats.

The worst result for the Conservatives in terms of vote-share was at the 1995 North Down by-election, with 2.1%, but that's in Northern Ireland rather than Great Britain.

| Year | Constituency | Electorate / Turnout | Conservative (%) | Labour (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997_Winchester_by-election) | Winchester | 79,161 / 54,384 | 15,450 (28.4%) | 944 (1.7%) |
| [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Newbury_by-election) | Newbury | 90,503 / 57,399 | 15,535 (26.9%) | 1,151 (2.0%) |

Comment: Voters seem to be more willing to vote tactically in by-elections, which may explain these low Labour results.

Answer (score 8):

**Before 1955**

I don't know enough about UK politics to know whether Conservative and Labour were both major parties, but in 1918 the Conservatives received 1.1% of the vote in [Pontypridd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontypridd_(UK_Parliament_constituency)#Elections_in_the_1910s), according to the results [here](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-8647/).

**Since 1955**

**(Original Answer)** Excepting constituencies where the Speaker was standing for reelection, I do not believe this has happened since 1955 based on the data [here](https://www.electoralcalculus.co.uk/flatfile.html), but perhaps an election at 2.2% is close enough?

Those data provide the total population, but here are the three lowest performances for either party:

| Year | Constituency | Electorate / Turnout | Conservative (%) | Labour (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westmorland_and_Lonsdale_(UK_Parliament_constituency)) | Westmorland and Lonsdale | 67,881 / 51,487 | 18,632 (36.2) | 1,158 (2.2) |
| [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaenau_Gwent_(UK_Parliament_constituency)) | Blaenau Gwent | 53,301 / 35,251 | 816 (2.4) | 11,384 (32.3) |
| [1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Wight_(UK_Parliament_constituency)#Elections_in_the_1980s) | Isle of Wight | 94,226 / 75,347 | 34,901 (51.0) | 1,828 (2.4) |

Comment: In 1918, the major parties were the Conservatives and the Liberals.

Comment: There's the 1935 Glasgow Bridgeton election as well - 2.18% for the Labour candidate. Not aware of any below 2% though.

Comment: @JoeC according to the linked Wikipedia article, not in Pontypridd  (Labour were second with 43%). 1918 was the year of the [Representation of the People Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_the_People_Act_1918), which really turned the electorate in Labour's favour by adding lots of working-class voters. Also the government at the time was a [complex cross-party coalition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd_George_ministry) which would complicate things further (the prime minister was a Liberal, but so were the official opposition)

Comment: @JoeC When did Labour become a "major party"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- The 1929 election was the first election Labour won, and the 1922 general election was the first election where Labour and Conservatives were the two biggest parties, although they managed over 20% of the vote in 1918, and over 6% in the two 1910 elections.

Comment: @James_pic Well then luckily it was the Conservatives that had a <2% result in 1918, not the Liberals.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Whenever it was, it isn't a major party any more. It was wiped out in Scotland by the Nationalists, and in England its "power base" is pretty much some Marxist intellectuals in large cities, plus those of its historical working-class trade-unionized supporters who haven't yet died of old age.